# Error: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have created an `NSMutableArray` to store some character there. When I'am adding some character there it gives me an error. Here my code:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *actions;     < ViewController.h

@synthesize actions;                                     < ViewController.m


actions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];    
switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 0:
            currentLabel = water;
            [actions insertObject:@"0" atIndex:i];
            i++;
            break;
        case 1:
            currentLabel = coke;
            [actions insertObject:@"1" atIndex:i];
            i++;
            break;
        case 2:
            currentLabel = fanta;
            [actions insertObject:@"2" atIndex:i];
            i++;
            break;
}
```

Comment: obviously you cannot insert an element at index `i` if the array has not had `i` elements already.

Comment: The first time you call the method `insertObject:`, `i` is 1 which should be zero.

Comment: `i` is initialized as `0`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[actions addObject:@"X"]` instead. If the array does not have elements, you can't insert object at index 1.

Comment: When I use `addObject` I only have one object in my Array.